# Struggling through AuthGuard in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Tried to follow AuthGuard example available here:
http://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/

Unfortunately, while trying to implement the `ActivationGuard.ts` file, I'm receiving few errors.

```
ERROR in C:/Users/app/src/app/ActivationGuard.ts (6,24): Cannot find name 'ActivatedRouteSna
pshot'.)
C:/Users/app/src/app/ActivationGuard.ts (6,55): Cannot find name 'RouterStateSnapshot'.)
C:/Users/app/src/app/ActivationGuard.ts (13,62): Cannot find name 'CurrentUserService'.)
C:/Users/app/src/app/ActivationGuard.ts (15,31): Cannot find name 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.)
C:/Users/app/src/app/ActivationGuard.ts (15,62): Cannot find name 'RouterStateSnapshot'.)
```

Which basically means that the elements inside the `CanActivate` interface and inside constructors are not defined.

`routing` file:

```
import { WorksheetAccessGuard } from "./ActivationGuard";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, 
  { path: 'app', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [WorksheetAccessGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

My question: From where could I get these missing elements?

Provided image of my IDE: (the red words are the missing ones)

## EDIT

I have made a custom service. I'm not sure if its fine or not:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserAuthenticationService {
    isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;
    username: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    authentication() {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/auth/isLogged/${this.username}`)
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.isUserAuthenticated = res.json();
                },
                err => {
                    console.error('An error occured.' + err);
                });
    }


}
```

Now I'm receiving some error inside the `AuthGuard` file:

[ERROR PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaUff.png)

**My main goal is checking with every component change (when user navigates over the page) if he is logged or not. If not - return him to the login page.

## EDIT2

Can I just post all logic from the service in the `AuthGuard` file? It will look like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {UserAuthenticationService} from './UserAuthenticationService';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
}

@Injectable()
export class WorksheetAccessGuard implements CanActivate {
    private static username: string;
    isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserAuthenticationService, private http: Http) {
    }

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

        this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/auth/isLogged/${this.username}`)
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.isUserAuthenticated = res.json();
                },
                err => {
                    console.error('An error occured.' + err);
                });

        if (!this.isUserAuthenticated) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RouterStateSnapshot` and `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` are imported from `@angular/router`, while the currentUser Service is supposed to be your own where you should store the authenticated state of your User (with a boolean for example).

You retrieve an instance of it through Dependency Injection in your guard's constructor like so :

```
import { CurrentUserService } from './path/to/your/service/file';
import { RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private userService: CurrentUserService) 
{}
```

Your service needs to be provided in your module, (as well as your guard), and you need to have a property like this in your CurrentUserService :

**CurrentUserService** :

```
isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
```

That way, when you log in from your Login Component (I assume you have one), you can set the service property to `true` :

**LoginComponent** :

```
import { CurrentUserService } from './path/to/your/service/file';

constructor(private userService: CurrentUserService) 
{}

login() {

... // Your existing code where you login on form submit or anything

this.userService.isAuthenticated = true;
}
```

**EDIT** :

Check out my example, it should fit for yours.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
        // Deny navigation and redirect to login
        this.router.navigate(['/path/to/login']);
        return false;
    }
    // Allow navigation (be careful that the guard always resolve a value)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point why should I drop it inside the login component? I have already an authentication implemented in login component, but now I want to check with every component change (user navigates on the site) if he is logged or not. If not - go back to the login page. I have made some service, I will post it in few minutes in my question.

Comment: Basically, the service here is only used to share the properties that you need to check to know if your user is logged in (I used `isAuthenticated` in my example). 

So when your user logs in, `isAuthenticated` is set to `true`; and your guard checks that value to either return `true` or `false` to allow the navigation or not. 

If you don't have properties to check in a service, your guard can't check anything himself, and if you don't set your service property, your guard will always return `false`.

Comment: And if Guard returns `false`, the user won't be able to navigate over the page? He will only be able to stay in login component, yes?

Comment: In your SparkBit example, the code is checking directly the user stored in the service, instead of a boolean property.
And yes, the navigation will be allowed depending on the guard resolve.
I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Done. This is a basic example with a boolean, you are free to store directly the user, his rights or whatever to do your own custom authentication guard.

Comment: This http request returns a boolean value, if user is currently logged or not. I just wonder, can I just put all logic from the service inside `AuthGuard` file? Check my edited post.

Comment: It is better to store it in a property, as you will only do the `http` call once. These ajax calls are costly, and putting it in the guard will make you do a lot of calls for nothing.